# SwiftUI the text color of destination from NavigationLink in List won't change when toggle darkmode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

The text of destination View of NavigationLink in List won't change its foreground color when uesr change appearance.

But the desitination View of the outside one works well.

See Video in https://oss.catrefuse.com/img/sample

sample code:

```swift
struct BugView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack {
        List {
          NavigationLink("Link in List", destination:   Text("Link in List") )
            .tag(UUID())
        }
        Spacer()
        NavigationLink("Link outside", destination:   Text("Link outside") )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in `macOS Ventura 13.0 beta7` / `iOS 16.0` / `Xcode 14.0`

- update: I found that it seems to be a problem with the new `NavigationStack` in SwiftUI 3.0, which will go away as using the old `NavigationView`

Comment: What do you mean "won't change its foreground color when user change appearance"?

Comment: see the video. When you turn the system appearence into darkmode, the background of destination view turns into black as normal but the text stays in black, which is expected to turn in white. @Yrb

Comment: Try it on device. At least right now, my simulators seem to be having issues with light/dark mode. On device it works flawlessly. One other thing, don't use `UUID()` with a tag. The whole point of the tag is to identify the view. `UUID()` changes on every refresh, so this ends up obscuring the identity of the view.

Comment: @Yrb Thanks for tag advice. Do you test it on iOS 15? I run it on iOS 16 physical device and the problem still exists.

Comment: @Yrb I just found the trigger - the problem will appear when using `NavigationStack`

Comment: If you are on iOS 15, you should be using a `NavigationView`.